# Boolean array masks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numpy

Coming from Python and Numpy, a typical feature I find myself using frequently are boolean masks.

Here's an example in Python:

```
>>> mylist = np.array([50, 12, 100, -5, 73])
>>> mylist == 12
array([False, True, False, False, False])  # A new array that is the result of ..
                                           # .. comparing each element to 12
>>> mylist > 0
array([True, True, True, False, True])     # A new array that is the result of ..
                                           # .. comparing each element to 0
>>> mylist[mylist == 12]
array([12])                                # A new array of all values at indexes ..
                                           # .. where the result of `mylist == 12` is True

>>> mask = mylist != 100                   # Save a mask
>>> map(foo, mylist[mask])                 # Apply `foo` where the mask is truthy
```

In general when `np.array` is indexed by another array of the same size, a new array is returned containing the elements at those indexes where the mask array's value is truthy.

I am able to do something similar with `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.filter` in Javascript but it's more verbose and my mask is destroyed.

```
-> mylist = [50, 12, 100, -5, 73]
-> mylist.map(item => item == 12)
<- [false, true, false, false, false]      // mylist == 12

-> mylist.filter(item => item == 12)
<- [12]                                    // mylist[mylist == 12]

-> mask = mylist.map(item => item == 12)
-> mylist.filter(item => mask.unshift())
<- [12]                                    // mylist[mask]

-> mask
<- []                                      // Mask isn't reusable
```

Is there a better way of applying masks over arrays in javascript or am I stuck making copies of masks and using `filter` and `map` each time?

Comment: [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array, it doesn't destroy the original.

Comment: `.unshift()` does though - otherwise I need an index for the mask entry.

Comment: The function passed to *filter* takes 3 arguments, the value, index and original object. So there's your index. Or write your own extension like `Array.prototype.maskFilter` which just takes the index.

Comment: Nice - didn't know about the extra arguments. Needless to say, I still have to use `map` and `filter` though right?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you'll have to write an equivalent for numpy. I'm not familiar with it, but I think there's enough here to work it out. There is also [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which is even more flexible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both *filter* and *map* create new arrays so they're fine. However, your use of *unshift* seems to be because you want the index rather than the value. You could pass the index in the call:

```js
var mylist = [50, 12, 100, -5, 73];
var mask = mylist.map(item => item == 12);
var newlist = mylist.filter((item, i) => mask[i]);

console.log(newlist);
```

or if you don't want to pass more then one value, you could write your own *maskFilter* method of Array.prototype that takes just a mask instead:

```js
Array.prototype.maskFilter = function(mask) {
  return this.filter((item, i) => mask[i]);
}

var mylist = [50, 12, 100, -5, 73];
var mask = mylist.map(item => item == 12);
var newlist = mylist.maskFilter(mask);


console.log(newlist); // [12]
console.log(mylist);  // untouched
```